# Facebook login button inside dialog

Tags: java, android, facebook, mobile

I want to display certain content on a section if the user is logged in. However, if the user isn't logged in, I would like to show a dialog prompting the user to login. I would also like to display the facebook login button inside this dialog.

However, the login button inside the dialog doesn't seem to work. And when I place it inside the activity layout, it does work.

Is there a way to make it function correctly inside the dialog?

Here is the dialog xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/heart"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/favorite_dialog"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_favorites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/heart"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explanation_favorites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/question_favorites"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

     <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:text="Cancelar"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This dialog is shown on the onCreate method, and it contains a cancel button which dismisses it.

I would appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this one out, it was quite simple, but not so elegant.

What I did was to put the facebook login button inside the main layout, hidden. Then, I set up a listener on the dialog button, and inside it I added "facebookLogin.performClick();".

That redirected the click to the facebook login listener.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I also stucked with same error. But finally I managed get it to work:

So: MainActivity opens WelcomeFragment. WelcomeFragment opens LoginDialog (my own dialog). In LoginDialog I have facebookLogin button.
Inside MainActivity I had everything I should have according to facebook's tutorial: UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper instance, which is invoked in onResume, onActivityResult, onPause, onDestroy and onSaveInstanceState. Login button in LoginDialog was initialized by following:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
authButton.setFragment(welcomeFragment);
```

But this was not working until I added onActivityResult to WelcomeFragment, same as in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Also it is described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2:

"During the authentication flow, the results are returned back to the main activity by default. Your activity would need to handle the results by overriding the onActivityResult() method. To allow the fragment to receive the onActivityResult() call rather than the activity, you can call the setFragment() method on the LoginButton instance."